# Subsection numbering flipped order

Tags: sectioning, polyglossia, arabic, themes, english

As you can see the numbers of the subsection is not ordered correctly, how can I fix that.

This template is from overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/fancy-analysis-report/hdygfmftrpds

The problem is caused because of that line but I need it to write Arabic.
`\setotherlanguages{arabic}`

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
% \usepackage{lipsum}
% \usepackage{natbib}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{analysis_orax}
\usepackage{xunicode} %% loading this first to avoid clash with bidi/arabic
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{hologo}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguages{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Noto Naskh Arabic}


% \usepackage[arabic]{babel}
%------------------Document----------------------------

\begin{document}

%-------------------------TitlePage------------------------
%\begin{titlepage}
%\end{titlepage}

%-------------------------Content------------------------

\section{Analysis Report}

\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}
\subsection{Subtitle}


\end{document}
```

But I have subsection numbers flipped.
[image]

Comment: Overleaf runs `bidi v19.6` which contains a bug. The workaround is to add `\usepackage{bidi}\makeatletter\@Latintrue\makeatother` just before `\begin{document}`. This workaround does not work and is no longer needed with `bidi v20.9` and later.

Comment: It gives me `!Undefined control sequence. \makeatletter\@Latinetrue`

Comment: Typo! Sorry. Should be `\@Latintrue`. I can't edit my comment now.